# Adb Install Failure INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE

Tags: android, installation, adb, downgrade

I uninstalled whatsapp and kept its data using:

```
adb.exe shell pm uninstall -k com.whatsapp
```

Then I tried to install an old version of whatsapp, but got the following error message even using the -r -d flags:

```
>adb install -r -d tmp\LegacyWhatsApp.apk
1738 KB/s (18329558 bytes in 10.298s)
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE]
```

I'm using Windows 10 and Pixel XL android version 7.1.2

Comment: Getting the same problem with Pixel and 7.1.2. Works on Nexus 5 on 6.0. Is this a Nougat thing?

Answer (score 4):

Since Android 7 (Nougat), [for security reasons](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/921dd75), packages can no longer be downgraded unless they are marked as debuggable. Quoting the commit message :

> An attacker could downgrade a package to an older version with known
>   security vulnerabilities and then use some of the vulnerabilities to
>   access the application's data. This would constitute a bypass of
>   Android Application Sandbox. Thus, downgrading while keeping
>   application data is no longer permitted.

You must uninstall it completely.